# how do you Change IIS authentication method to BasicAuthentication?

Tags: iis-7, basic-authentication, iis-modules

I try to Change IIS authentication method to BasicAuthentication for IIS7? 
I try to follow the steps [here](http://vivekthangaswamy.blogspot.com/2009/07/aspnet-website-cannot-read.html), because I get that error
Thank you

PS: I was trying [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009%28WS.10%29.aspx), but I have only this options
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled the Basic Authentication Module? Here's a [guide](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/authentication/basicAuthentication).